# Two identical fermions in a box and the spin-statistics theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, pauli-exclusion-principle

Consider the case of two identical non-interacting spin 1/2 particles in a box, whose length is $L$ with walls at $x=0$ and $x=L$. The Hamiltonian in this case (setting $m=1/2$, $\hbar=1$) is
$$
H=H_1+H_2=p_1^2+p_2^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}.
$$

For each of these Hamiltonians separately, the eigenfunctions are $ \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin(\frac{\pi x_{1,2}}{L}n) $ if $n$ is odd or $ \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \cos(\frac{\pi x_{1,2}}{L}n) $ if $n$ is even and the corresponding energies $E_n=\frac{\pi^2}{L^2} n^2$ where $n=1,2,3...$. Normally we cannot have $n=0$ as that means there is no particle, however under the total Hamiltonian we can still describe a state in which there is only a single particle, $\psi(x_1,x_2)=\sin(\frac{\pi x_1}{L})$ for example. $H_2$ acts on it to give 0, while it remains an eigenfunction of $H_1$. So then we can, on principle, write it as$\;| 01 \rangle$, that is $n_1=1$ $n_2=0$.

I was trying to make sense of this under the spin-statistics theorem. For spin 1/2 particles, the theorem requires the total wavefunction to be antisymmetric in respect to particle exchange. So then it seems that an appropriate spatial ground state would be (among other options)

$$
\;| \psi_{12} \rangle = \;| 01 \rangle+\;| 10 \rangle
$$
$$
\psi(x_1,x_2)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi x_1}{L})+\sin(\frac{\pi x_2}{L})}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Plug this into the total Hamiltonian and we see that it is indeed an eigenfunction. With equal probabilities we can measure either one particle existing, or the other. Now to make the total wavefunction anti-symmetric, the spin function should be

$$
\;| \;S_{12} \rangle = \frac{\;| \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2} \rangle - \;| -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

And this is where the nonsense begins. Mathematically it still works, but it looks like we're saying that a particle which doesn't exist has spin. If a perturbation is added to the Hamiltonian we can even get these phantom particles and spins to interact resulting in a change in energy, though there are weirder things in QM. It is also tempting to say that the spin-statistics theorem doesn't apply if there is only one particle actually in existence, but then how can we say that it is particle 1 which exists rather than particle 2?

So my question is: Is this state viable? Can we at all describe a state with only one particle under a Hamiltonian which has room for two? What exactly is a particle for the purpose of the spin-statistics theorem?

Comment: Your wavefunctions should be sums of *products*, i.e. combinations of the form $\psi_a(x_1)\psi_b(x_2)$.  Moreover you need to include the spin part as well since spin-statistics applies to spatial$\times$ spin.

Comment: Also your solution isn’t properly normalized because the integral of the cross-term in $\sin(\pi x_1/L)\sin(\pi x_2/L)$ is not $0$ (amongst other things).

Comment: “ With equal probabilities we can measure either one particle existing, or the other”: that’s not a 2-particle state…

Comment: Your proposed wavefunction even in the single-particle case is outside the domain of the Hamiltonian (i.e. outside the Hilbert space), because a priori the wavefunctions for a particle in a box are restricted to go to zero at the edges. We physically justify this by noting the wavefunction should extend (as a zero function) outside the box. (Extending yours gives infinite derivatives.) There is no reason to believe the two particle Hilbert space (which you build by tensoring two of the single-particle spaces) should be extended to wavefunctions of this form (the infinite derivatives remain).

Comment: @HTNW You're right I meant 0 to L not -L/2 to L/2 (fixed it now)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly valid, and actually good, question

Comment: Regarding the interpretation: rather than we have "equal probabilities we can measure either one particle existing, or the other", you know that your system has one particle. But since you can't follow a particle you can't know which one it is. (it's only a slight change but it might help with your question).